# Is there a more efficient way of saving checkboxes checked state?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, save, settings

So I'm making a checklist app in which I want to include a "Save" button to save the checked state of all checkboxes **(In Visual Studio 2019 and c#)**. Right now, I have 65 checkboxes (one for each task), but there will be many many more in the future.

So, following instructions, I went to the project's **properties**, went to **Settings**  and created a **new setting** with type "bool", scope "user" and value "False". Then, I created my GetSettings() function, like so:

```
public void GetSettings()
    {
        checkBox1.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBox1;
    }
```

and a SaveSettings() like so:

```
public void GetSettings()
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBox1 = checkBox1.Checked;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
```

Then I added *SaveSettings()* and *GetSettings()* to *SaveButton_Click*, and *GetSettings()* to *Form1_Load* as well.

That obviously works like a charm, and for a more simple form with like 5 checkboxes I don't mind adding a new setting for each one and declaring it in the functions, but with 65+ checkboxes the work gets a little bit copious.

I tried just looping through the checkboxes with a *foreach loop* but it obviously didn't work as intended; and I've tried many things now that I just don't remember. I have searched and searched and haven't found a way to do this, maybe I didn't know what to look for, since I'm at a very beginner level.

Anyway, does anyone know a more efficient way to save the state of my checkboxes and loading the next time I open the application? Any way will do as long as it works (plus I might learn something new).

Thank you in advance, and If you need any more information or I haven't explained myself clearly, I'll gladly respond!

EDIT:
I have all checkboxes inside a Flow Layout Panel, and what I tried for looping through each box is:

```
foreach (CheckBox chk in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBox1 = chk.Checked;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
```

and for Getting such settings:

```
foreach (CheckBox chk in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
    {
        chk.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.CheckBox1;
    }
```

But what that does is getting them all checked or unchecked when I click the Save button. Maybe I'm doing it wrong!

Comment: Why do you need to visit all the controls at startup?  Set the desired value with the Forms Designer and compile it with each set however you like.

Comment: Use application settings binding.

Comment: Well, I'd suggest that you loop through each checkbox, but you say you've tried that, *"but it obviously didn't work as intended"*. The code I envisage is very simple. What does your obviously wrong code look like? Perhaps you could show it as a [mcve]

Comment: hi @Flydog57 I added the loop i was trying to use in the EDIT section of my question

Comment: hi @RezaAghaei I read about that and tried things with that but I don't remember and silly me didn't save what I did anywhere, but I know it did weird stuff like checking every checkbox when clicking one of them

Comment: Don't forget to `Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade()` to refresh your values

Comment: @AndrewToasterr  You don't want to do that. `Upgrade()` doesn't *refresh* the values. It does something different (completely).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try to save the settings in `App.config` file.

First, you can add the node `appSettings` like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>

    <appSettings>
        <add key="CheckBox1" value="True" />
        <add key="CheckBox2" value="True" />
        <add key="CheckBox3" value="False" />
    </appSettings>

    <!--...-->
</configuration>
```

And then add the reference `System.Configuration`.

[image]

Last step, you can use the following code to get/save the settings.

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

private void btGetSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(Control control in this.Controls)
    {
        // Check if is CheckBox
        if (control is CheckBox)
        {
            // Read the setting in App.config
            string value = config.AppSettings.Settings[control.Name].Value;
            ((CheckBox)control).Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(value);
        }
    }
    // Save and refresh settings
    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
}

private void btSaveSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
    {
        if (control is CheckBox)
        {
            // Modify the setting in App.config
            config.AppSettings.Settings[control.Name].Value = ((CheckBox)control).Checked.ToString();
        }
    }
    // Save and refresh settings
    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
}
```

Comment: hey! Thanks a bunch, this worked! I wanted to do something like this but never understood how all this xml stuff worked, and now I do and I can continue with this project, because I was really stuck there. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You could use ResXResourceWriter and -Reader classes

```
// Save
var rw = new ResXResourceWriter(<your file>);

foreach (CheckBox box in Form.Controls)
{
    rw.AddResource(box.ToString(), box.Checked);
}

rw.Close();

// Read
var rr = ResXResourceReader(<your file>);

foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in rr)
{
    var box = Form.Controls
               .First(x => x.ToString() == entry.Key.ToString());
    box.Checked = (bool)entry.Value;
}

rr.Close();
```

This probably has some errors, i did not have time to test it